# Cannot append items to end of list and concatenate data frames

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am looping through data frame columns to obtain specific pieces of data - so far I have been successful except for the last three pieces of data I need. When I attempt to append these pieces of data to the list, they are appended to the beginning of the list and not at the end (I need them to be at the end).

Therefore, when I convert this list into a data frame and attempt to concatenate it to another data frame I have prepared, the values are all in the wrong places.

This is my code:

```
descs = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
data =[]
stats = []
for desc in descs:
    data.append({
        "Description":desc
    })
for column in df:
    if df[column].name == "column1":
        counts = df[column].value_counts()
        stats.extend([
            counts.sum(), 
            counts[True], 
            counts[False] 
        ])
    elif df[column].name == "date_column":
        stats.append(
            df[column].min().date()
        )
    #Everything is fine up until this `elif` block
    #I THINK THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS I DONT KNOW HOW TO FIX IT
    elif df[column].name == "column2":
        stats.extend([
            df[column].max() ,
            round(df[column].loc[df["column1"] == True].agg({column:"mean"}),2),
            round(df[column].loc[df["column1"] == False].agg({column:"mean"}),2)
        ])
```

Up until the second `elif`block, when I run this code and concatenate `data` and `stats` as data frames `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data), pd.DataFrame({"Statistic":stats}), axis = 1)` I get the following output - which is the output I want:

| Description | Statistic |
| --- | --- |
| "a" | 38495 |
| "b" | 3459 |
| "c" | 234 |
| "d" | 1984-06-2 |
| "e" | NaN |
| "f" | NaN |
| "g" | NaN |

When I run the above code chunk including the second `elif` block, the output is messed up

| Description | Statistic |
| --- | --- |
| "a" | [78, [454],[45]] |
| "b" | 38495 |
| "c" | 3459 |
| "d" | 234 |
| "e" | 1984-06-2 |
| "f" | NaN |
| "g" | NaN |

Those values in the first index of the data frame [78, 454, 45] **should be in the place (and in that order) where NaNs appear in the first table**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close to making this work the way you want!

A couple things to make your life simpler:

1. df[column].name isn't needed because you can just use column
2. Looping through columns and having multiple if statements on their names to calculate summary statistics works, but you'll make your life easier if you look into .groupby() with .agg()

And that brings me to your issue: .agg() returns a pandas Series, and you just want a single number. Try

```
round(df[column].loc[df["column1"] == False].mean(),2)
```

instead. :)

Update: Now it looks like you are hitting the second elif with the first column, so re-order your DataFrame columns to be in the order you want them in:

```
cols = ["column1", "date_column", "column2"]
for column in cols:
  if column == "column1":
```

Comment: The values I want are now in the correct format, but I'm still getting the same issue of the values not being in order. After having appended the datetime value the list called `stats` looks like this [78, 454, 45, 38495, 3459, 234, datetime.date(1984-06-2)] When it should look like this [38495, 3459, 234, datetime.date(1984-06-2), 78, 454, 45] <-- those last three values appended to the **end of the list**

Comment: Well since you are using `if` statements along with `.append()` and `.extend()`, that tells me "column2" is the first one in the dataframe, right? I'll edit my answer so that your columns are sorted the way you want.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! Why does it work? And yes "column2" was the first one in the data frame, how did you know that?

Comment: The `.append()` and `.extend()` functions will only add onto the end of the list. So if the results for column2 are at the beginning, that must mean column2 is the first column. Glad I could help! Would you please accept my solution so I get reputation points? :)

Comment: Yup, I gave the upvote and the tick

Comment: Above and beyond. Thanks!